# Unable to parse AMF model

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Get error when running Mulesoft app from Anypoint Studio - run the app, clicking console button in Studio opens browser and throws error "Unable to parse AMF model."

Found potential resolution here:
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Unable-to-parse-AMF-model-error-with-APIKit-Console

But I do not know how to get to these option in Anypoint Studio to try and see if they resolve the issue for me.

I get the same error on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: The question is too generic and no details for reproduction were provided.

Comment: I'm going through the training and up till that point had followed along and everything worked just fine. I'm not sure if there's been some changes since the training was developed but at this point I don't know enough about this software to really provide much more detail than I did. I thought the error message would have been specific enough to get some suggestions on where to look.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with the router config and the solution shared above from MuleSoft did not work. When pulling an API down from Exchange there was something wrong with the Router. If you are look at the Global Elements tab next to Message Flow in the IDE you should see an entry there for Router. It was almost as if the router didn't exist so I clicked the Create button. Once it was there and I could edit it I selected the option to Keep RAML/OAS base URI and to set the Parser option to AUTO. This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: In the end, after fixing the above, it was still not working. What worked for me was forcing the parser format to RAML. It seems that the AUTO mode is not that smart.